# Postgres calculate growth rate over two month

Tags: postgresql

I would like to calculate growth rate for customers for following data.

```
 month         | customers
-------------------------
01-2015        |   1
02-2015        |   10
03-2014        |   10
06-2015        |   15
```

I have used following formula to calculate the growth rate, it works only for one month interval as well as not able to give expected output due to gap between 3rd and 6th month as shown in above table

```
select
    month, total,
    (total::float / lag(total) over (order by month) - 1) * 100 growth
from (
    select to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm') as month, count(id) total
    from customers
    group by month
) s
order by month;
```

I think this can be done by creating a date range and group by that range.

I expect two main output separately
1) Generate growth rate with exact one month difference
2) Growth rate with interval of 2 month instead of single month only. In above data sum the two month result and group by two month instead of month

Comment: what is the question?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Question is how to calculate effective and correct growth rate, with all monthly interval without skipping any month

Comment: At some point you might also find the statistical aggregate functions to be of use, for calculating linear regression for example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about the second part. Here's growth from your adapted query and twon month growth column:

```
select
    month, total,
    (total::float / lag(total) over (order by m) - 1) * 100 growth,m,m2
from (
    select created, (sum(customers) over (order by m))::float total,customers,m,m2,to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm') as month
    from customers c
    right outer join (
        select generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-06-01','1 month'::interval) m
    ) m1 on m=c.created
    left outer join (
        select generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-06-01','2 month'::interval) m2
    ) m2 on m2=m
    order by m
) s
order by m;
```

[image]

basically answer is **use generate_series**

Comment: Second point is: I wants to generate growth rate for two month grouping instead of one month thats it, FIrst and second points are different 
And they do defer in terms of growth period, in first I have one month period, while in second that is replaced with twon month

Comment: In above result image, you are showing total 21 for 4th and 5th month, which should be 0, dont you think?
In first month I got 1 customer, in second I got 10 similarly for I have 10 customer for third 
But it seems you have sum with the previous, can you explain your query?

Comment: total in my query is total quantity of customers - why would it drop to zero when does not grow?.. growth drops on its turn... @ram Lets do the other way - put the table with expected results to your question :)